# Is any way to ignore user agent then sending hit using Google Analytics measurement protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, user-agent, measurement-protocol

My website sends usual Page views and events to GA using JavaScript API.
Days after user session, I need to send more data from server using Measurement Protocol.

After sending the nonInteractive hit with updated custom dimensions, I see that  user's device category changed from the original device category (Desktop/Mobile/Tablet) to **Desktop** device category.

I understand that GA recognize server's User-Agent as Desktop device.

Is any way to make GA **ignore** server's User-Agent?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the user agent by collecting the users user agent at the time which you are collecting their client id, and sending this user agent along with the measurement protocol hit with the key **ua=**.

For example:

```
v=1              // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555         // Anonymous Client ID.

&t=pageview      // Pageview hit type.
&uip=1.2.3.4     // IP address override.
&ua=Opera/9.80   // User agent override.
```

For an overview see:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ua

For specific reference see:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ua

Comment: Thanks, That exactly that I going to do. Will update if it works